# Maven: Can I use a version from dependency management in annotationProcessorPath?

Tags: maven, lombok, annotation-processing

I'm importing a shared "bill of materials" (bom) in my dependencyManagement, like this:

```
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
      <artifactId>common-bom</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.3</version>
      <scope>import</scope>
      <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

That `common-bom` defines versions, and then I just use whatever version it defines, like this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
  <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

That's all working great, except that I also have this

```
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <annotationProcessorPaths combine.children="append">
        <annotationProcessorPath>
          <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
          <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
          <version>1.18.20</version>
        </annotationProcessorPath>
      </annotationProcessorPaths>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

So now I anyway need to specify a lombok version, not for the actual dependency, but for the annotation processor path. Is there a way I can somehow use the same value? Can it for example be stored as a property in the common-bom?

Comment: I don't think that is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible because maven-compiler-plugin does not currently follow `dependencyManagement` rules ([MCOMPILER-391](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MCOMPILER-391), go vote for it!).

The only thing you can do for now it seems is to declare a `lombok.version` property in the parent pom, and use that in your `annotationProcessorPath` declaration.

(note that Spring Boot already defines such a property for Lombok)